# Compare specific text with page Url then remove text partially

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of events and each event has a list of speakers. The speakers roles are showing as custom classification in a ul>li format for each speaker.  What I am trying to do is to alter their role names and remove the event title part from their tags. I need this logic to work for all events so I thought I can check the event Url and compare them against the tags and then remove event title part from the tags.

This is how event Urls will look like: /event-a, /event-b, /event-c, etc.

and this is how the tags are showing depending on the event:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Event a co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a chair</span></li>
</ul>
```

or:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Event b co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b chair</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is how I am getting the last segment of the Url and I also have a conditional that is checking if the tags are matching with the event Url:

```
pageUrl = window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, '');
var lastSeg = pageUrl.substr(pageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// loop
$('ul li').each(function () {
    var tagItemName = $(this).children('span').text();
    var tagItem = $(this).children('span').text().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    if (tagItem.indexOf(lastSeg) >= 0) {
        $(this).addClass('matching-tag');
    }
});
```

How do I squeeze in my "find and partial-remove" logic in the above code? Can it be in the same if statement?  I also have `tagItemName` which is the raw version of the tags without dashes and lowercasing.

What I am trying to achieve is this format in all events with the same code:

```
<ul>
 <li><span>co-chair</span></li>
 <li><span>speaker</span></li>
 <li><span>committee</span></li>
 <li><span>chair</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you could have it in the same if statement

```js
pageUrl = "www.mysite.com/Event-a"
//window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, '');
var lastSeg = pageUrl.substr(pageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// loop
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var tagItemName = $(this).children('span').text();
  if ($(this).children('span').text()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(lastSeg.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    $(this).text($(this).children('span').text().toLowerCase()
      .replace(lastSeg.replace('-', ' ').toLowerCase(), '')
      .trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
    $(this).addClass('matching-tag');
  }
});
```

```css
.matching-tag {background-color: coral;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><span>Event a co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a chair</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span>Event b co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b chair</span></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, the only thing is if the tag is multiple words then it places a dash between them, is there a way to avoid the dash? Or can it be removed after?

Comment: if you remove ```.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))```  you can still achieve the same thing as you don't need that, I posted a new answer above with other words in the span, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

update

```js
pageUrl = "www.mysite.com/Event-a"
//window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, '');
let lastSeg = pageUrl.substr(pageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// loop
$('ul li').each(function() {
  let tagItemName = $(this).children('span').text();
  if ($(this).children('span').text()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(lastSeg.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    $(this).text($(this).children('span').text().toLowerCase()
      .replace(lastSeg.replace('-', ' ').toLowerCase(), '')
      .trim())
    $(this).addClass('matching-tag');
  }
})
```

```css
.matching-tag {background-color: coral;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><span>Event a foo co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a bar speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a moo committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event a poo chair</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><span>Event b foo co-chair</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b bar speaker</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b moo committee</span></li>
    <li><span>Event b poo chair</span></li>
</ul>
```

hopefully this is better